# Using locally emulated https.onCall Firebase functions in locally hosted Firebase application

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a Firebase application using the node SDK and vanilla JavaScript on the client side. I am using Firebase Cloud Functions to implement a server that receives requests for my page routes and returns rendered HTML with the `https.onRequest` method. I am also using Cloud Functions to handle client-server interaction with the `https.onCall` method.

I develop locally using the `firebase serve` command. When developing locally, my client seems ignores my local `onCall` functions, instead calling the route for the deployed `onCall` functions. I am forced to deploy my `onCall` functions in order to see changes locally. If I do not deploy each change, my local app will not show any changes to `onCall` functions. This happens whether I run `firebase serve` or `firebase serve --only=hosting,functions`.

When I run my app locally with `firebase serve`, the pages are generally hosted at `localhost:5000`. The functions are hosted at `localhost:5001`. If I call a cloud function on one of these locally hosted pages, like `firebase.functions().httpsCallable('functionName')` and check the Network panel in my developer tools, I can see the Request URL is `https://us-central1-<app-name>.cloudfunctions.net/<functionName>`, instead of `localhost:5001/<app-name>/us-central1/<functionName>`.

This is frustrating me because it means I have to deploy my functions to test each change, rather than testing my local functions through my locally hosted web application.

Have I configured something incorrectly? How can I get my locally hosted app to use my locally emulated `onCall` cloud functions?

I am not making a single page application or using any view frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated version for Firebase v9.x.x:

```js
import { getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";

const functions = getFunctions(getApp());
connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5001);

httpsCallable(functions, 'helloWorld')({foo: "bar"}).then((res) => ...)
```

Answer (score 16):

<strike>It seems like Firebase has yet to implement a solution to point to the local server, so I came up with a little hack. Include the below snippet where you initialize your Firebase project. Hope it helps!</strike>

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  firebase.functions()._url = function (name) {
    return `${process.env.API_URL}/${name}`
  }
}
```

EDIT: Like **goker.cebeci** commented below, the correct way to connect to your local emulator is to use `functions.useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001')` (change `http://localhost:5001` to whatever address your local emulator is running on)

The updated code looks like this:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const functions = firebase.functions()
  functions.useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001')
}
```

Comment: Is this used on the client side or sever side? I cannot seem to get it to work as intended. Can you provide a bit more context?

Comment: It all depends on your configuration. I'm using Vue and the prebuilt env variable configuration. During development NODE_ENV will be 'development' and when building for production it will be 'production', so the above code will be ignored. If that doesn't help you maybe this will https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: Since you're using environment variables, I assume you're placing this block on the server side where the functions are initialized, in a file like `functions/index.js`. Can you provide a large example block showing what specific `firebase` variable your code refers to, and where this declaration should come in relation to function definitions?

Comment: No these are client side variables. You can see how. You can see how Vue utilizes these in this template for example: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

Comment: Also, you can use `functions.useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001');`  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.functions.Functions